# Can I display 2 images at the same time at python?

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, imshow

I'm working now with image processing and for debugging I want to see both the image before processing and after.
I'm using pycharm.
Can I display 2 images, one at a window, at the same time?

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried to do so?

Comment: You can do it in two windows by naming them differently, you can do it in one by concatenating the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)

ax[0].imshow(img1) #first image
ax[1].imshow(img2) #second image
plt.show()
```